# Wrong price for configurable product in cart

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I'm currently using Simple Configurable Products on my site but am having a few with displaying the correct price on the cart

I have a configurable product which has say three simple products within it with different prices. 
The price on the product page displays correctly but when I go to the cart the prices of all the simple products are the price of the first simple product.
For example
Configurable Product 1
       Simple Product 1 - 19.00
       Simple Product 2 - 25.00
       Simple Product 3 - 35.00

If I had checkout with simple product 3 the price in the cart is 19.00

Would really appreciate a bit of guidance on this on

Thanks

Comment: hi @johnson64. If you're question is resolved please close it. Otherwise it'll keep popping up on the unresolved list :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/spVj88T4 Try copy and paste this to app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php It works for most people, but I still have no luck on it.

Answer (score 1):

I've just fixed the same bug which was caused by the `Excellence Ajaxcart` extension. The issue is with a controller that was overwritten by the `Excellence` extension which prevented the `Simple Configurable Products` extension from overwriting the same controller.

I would advice you to check which 3th party extensions are overwriting the controllers and either let them play nicely together or, this is what I did, let the client decide which one of the 2 extensions they want to keep and uninstall the other one.

Comment: Still no luck. I really would like the Ajax cart still enabled. I would prefer to fix the conflict. When you was debugging the problem did you manage to find exactly where the conflict was?

Comment: the issue was 2 conflicting controller rewrites. They were both using their own controller so which ever extension was loaded first into the core won. To make them work together would, I'd guess, taking the controller that isn't working and adding it's functionality to the working controller or calling the not working controller from the working one but both methodes will require a lot of modifications and debugging.

Comment: Not sure why but SCP doesn't seem to be working in the checout at all.

Comment: that's correct, Ajax Cart is probably overwriting the controller that is handling the way SCP adds product so the part where SCP adds the product to cart is completely bypassed

Comment: You was right Sander

Comment: Thanks. THe only problem I'm facing now is when I try to remove a product from the basket I'm getting a javascript error "Error: Unable to process the request"

Comment: Try and do some basic debugging and try to backtrace the error in the code. Post what you can find in a new question to keep on topic :)

Comment: Sorted! Thanks for the help today man! Huge help

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help